Unable to Filter MongoDB Documents by Nested Fields in Node.js Using Mongoose
I'm working on implementing a GET request in my Node.js application, where I need to retrieve data based on various filters provided in the request query. However, I'm facing issues with filtering documents by nested fields in MongoDB using Mongoose.
Here's how my project model looks:
const projectAddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    street: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    city: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    postalCode: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    country: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { _id: false }
);

const priceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    layout: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      enum: ["studio", "1kk", "2kk", "3kk", "4kk", "5kk"],
    },
    amount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    currency: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    size: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { _id: false }
);

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  projectName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: [priceSchema],
  projectLink: {
    type: String,
  },
  projectDescription: {
    type: String,
  },
  projectImages: [String],
  projectAddress: projectAddressSchema,
});

const Project = mongoose.model("Project", projectSchema);


And here's my GET controller:
exports.getAllProjects = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.query);
    const features = new APIFeatures(Project.find(), req.query)
      .filter()
      .sort()
      .paginate()
      .limitFields();

    const projects = await features.query;
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      results: projects.length,
      projects,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new ServerError(err));
  }
};


My APIFeatures class handles filtering, sorting, pagination, and field limiting.
class APIFeatures {
  constructor(query, queryString) {
    this.query = query;
    this.queryString = queryString;
  }

  filter() {
    const queryObj = { ...this.queryString };
    const excludedFields = ["page", "sort", "limit", "fields"];
    excludedFields.forEach((el) => delete queryObj[el]);

    let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObj);
        queryStr = queryStr.replace(
      /\b(gte|gt|lte|lt|eq)\b/g,
      (match) => `$${match}`
    );

    for (const key in queryObj) {
      if (key.includes(".")) {
        const [outerKey, innerKey] = key.split(".");
        queryObj[outerKey] = {
          ...queryObj[outerKey],
          [innerKey]: queryObj[key],
        };
        delete queryObj[key];
      }
    }

    this.query = this.query.find(queryObj);

    return this;
  }

  sort() {
    if (this.queryString.sort) {
      const sortBy = this.queryString.sort.split(",").join(" ");
      this.query = this.query.sort(sortBy);
    } else {
      this.query = this.query.sort("-createdAt");
    }

    return this;
  }

  limitFields() {
    if (this.queryString.fields) {
      const fields = this.queryString.fields.split(",").join(" ");
      this.query = this.query.select(fields);
    } else {
      this.query = this.query.select("-__v");
    }

    return this;
  }

  paginate() {
    const page = this.queryString.page * 1 || 1;
    const limit = this.queryString.limit * 1 || 100;
    const skip = (page - 1) * limit;

    this.query = this.query.skip(skip).limit(limit);

    return this;
  }
}
module.exports = APIFeatures;


However, when I make a request like /projects?price.layout[eq]=studio, I expect to receive only projects with studio type apartments. Or /projects?price.layout[gte]=6000000, i expect to retrive all appartments started from 6000000.Instead, I'm getting all projects from the database.
{
    "status": "success",
    "results": 2,
    "projects": [
        {
            "_id": "665493755fbd1773ab3f30bf",
            "projectName": "Project 1",
            "price": [
                {
                    "layout": "studio",
                    "amount": 6000000,
                    "currency": "CZK",
                    "size": 30
                },
                {
                    "layout": "1kk",
                    "amount": 8000000,
                    "currency": "CZK",
                    "size": 50
                }
            ],
            "projectLink": "https://projectlink.com",
            "projectDescription": "Project description",
            "projectImages": [
                "image1.jpg",
                "image2.jpg"
            ],
            "projectAddress": {
                "street": "456 Project St",
                "city": "Project City",
                "postalCode": "67890",
                "country": "Project Country"
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "6654939f5fbd1773ab3f30c4",
            "projectName": "Project 2",
            "price": [
                {
                    "layout": "studio",
                    "amount": 5000000,
                    "currency": "CZK",
                    "size": 30
                },
                {
                    "layout": "1kk",
                    "amount": 9000000,
                    "currency": "CZK",
                    "size": 50
                }
            ],
            "projectLink": "https://projectlink.com",
            "projectDescription": "Project description",
            "projectImages": [
                "image1.jpg",
                "image2.jpg"
            ],
            "projectAddress": {
                "street": "456 Project St",
                "city": "Project City",
                "postalCode": "67890",
                "country": "Project Country"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Can someone please guide me on how to correctly implement filtering for nested fields in MongoDB using Mongoose?
I tried to googling the problem and i tried to use aggregation, but it didnt help. Also i found out that server can't get a res.query with price.layout. I have to use qs library. It helped to retrive an query, but still not filtering the whole document.

Can I ask if you are following an online tutorial or course because this APIFeatures class seems to be prevalent at the minute? It's adding another layer of abstraction on top of mongoose which is already abstracted from the native driver.

@jQueeny Yes, I am following an online course. The APIFeatures class adds another layer of abstraction on top of Mongoose. It is considered a good practice to avoid modifying the original parameters directly; instead, we create a copy and modify that copy.

When performing queries on arrays there are differences to what is returned and what you expect the shape of the documents to look like. There are nuances to the process. A one size fits all approach such as the APIFeatures class you have will not fit all. For example if you query {"price.layout" : {$eq: "studio"}} then you'll get back everything from the parent document. That means all elements in price array, not just the ones your query object matches. Remember you are matching a document based on a test condition.

Consider  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

@jQueeny thank you for your help. I tryied that sintax from docs in mongosh and i got exactly what i needed. I wil try to adapt my filter() to get expected response.

Sounds like you solved it. The projection operator has includes and excludes which can be a bit of a gotcha - just as a tip.

@jQueeny i have soled only how to query by parameters, but i have not solved how to use it with my API to combine different queries :D. But i am on my way. Thank you
